# Reversing a while loop shape?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

So i'm trying to reverse the output of the shape i currently made. I was wondering should i reverse the condition? I tried changing the value of variables "a" and "c" and i ended up getting an infinite loop.

```
class IRT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 2;
        int b;
        int c = 6;

        do {
            b = a - 1;
            if (b != 0) {
                do {
                    System.out.print("*");
                    b--;

                } while (b >= 1);
            }
            b = 1;
            do {
                System.out.print(" ");
                b++;

            } while (b <= (c - a + 1));

            System.out.println();
            a++;
        } while (a <= c);

    }

}
```

XML CODE

```
   My output                    What i'm trying to get

   *                                           *
   **                                         **
   ***                                       ***
   ****                                     ****
   *****                                   *****
```

Comment: I agree with Eran about indentation.  Please also use meaningful variable names such as `rowNumber`- you won't be sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is reverse the order of each row (i.e. first print the spaces and then print the `*`s), you just have to change the order to the two internal while loops.

```
  int a=2;
  int b;
  int c=6;

  do{
    b=1;
    do{
      System.out.print(" ");
      b++;

    }while(b <= (c - a + 1));

    b = a - 1;
    if (b!=0){
      do{
        System.out.print("*");
        b--;

      }while(b >= 1);
    }

    System.out.println();
    a++;

  } while(a <= c);
```

P.S. indenting your code makes it much easier to understand.

Output :

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by others, you should indend code and give meaningful names. Being **much** easier to completely rewrite your code, I took some time to simplify the code and to share the steps:

---

**1:**
I replaced do-while loops with infinite loops with breaks as they're hard to read. I consider `while(true)` with `break` and `continue` statement (`break label`, too) as low-level operations, they behave like meaningful `goto`s.

```
int a = 2;
int b;
int c = 6;

while(true) {
    b = a - 1;
    if (b != 0) {
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("*");
            b--;
            if(b < 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    b = 1;
    while (true){
        System.out.print(" ");
        b++;
        if(b > (c - a + 1)) {
            break;
        }

    }

    System.out.println();
    a++;
    if(a > c) {
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**2:**
I identified the loops to be best as for loops (postfix increments/decrements (`i++`/`i--`) are signs for that).

```
int a = 2;
int b;
int c = 6;

for (; a <= c; a++) {
    b = a - 1;
    if (b != 0) {
        for (; b >= 1; b--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    b = 1;

    for (; b <= c - a; b++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

---

**3:**
I put the temporarily used variable `b` to the for loop init statement to clarify the lifetime of the variable and its actual usage. `c` never changes, so I thought of it as a *constant* parameter.

```
final int c = 6;

for (int a = 2; a <= c; a++) {
    if (a != 1) {
        for (int b = a - 1; b >= 1; b--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    for (int b = 1; b <= c - a; b++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

**4:**
I did **a lot** of index transformations and reversed the counting directions to count up; `if(a != 1)` in step 3 was always true, so removed the redundant if branch.

> Side note:
>   A for loop of the form `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` (=count `i=0` up to `n-1`, having `n` iterations) can be applied as a simple pattern. You can transform the index in the loop body (`for(int i = 0; i < n;) { int index = i + offset; }`) or in the head (`for(int i = offset; i < n + offset; i++)`). You can reverse the counting direction - `for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)` (=count `i=n-1` down to `0`, having `n` iterations). They are useful, but please don't abuse them - only use the basic and reversed for loops with index transformations. Not some spaghetti code like `for(;;)`, `for(int i=0, j=4; i<j && i%j==0; i++,j+=2)` or `for(PrintStream out = System.out;;out.println("Hello World!")) break;`...

```
final int c = 5;
for (int a = 0; a < c; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < a + 2; b++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < c - (a + 1); b++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

**5:**
You may have noticed that I changed `final int c` to be equal to `6` instead of `5`. That's because I discovered it to be related to the row count and width, but just one unit bigger. In this step, I gave meaningful names to the variables, except `i` as this is a temporary counter for writing *n* times a character.

```
final int size = 5;
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - (row + 1); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row + 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Reading the code of step 5 and taking a look at the question, it comes to mind that the order of printing `*` and  needs to be swapped. So, here is finally the answer to your question:

```
final int size = 5;
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - (row + 1); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row + 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```